# MySQL: creating loose relationships between tables

Tags: mysql

I don't know the exact term so the use of the word "loose". Anyway, I have a small inventory system. All items are supposed to be located in stores. But some items might just arrive and are not placed. The items were in separate tables (placed and unplaced) but the process of moving them back and forth is not a pleasant experience.

So, I was thinking of putting the items in one column and use a column store_code.

```
        stores: id,name
        items: id,store_id,name
```

But that forces items to have a store regardless. Is there away to make store_id=0 so I can simply switch the column only back and forth.

Comment: add a simple flag  boolean isPlaced ?

Comment: I thot of that but clients need to know in which store an item is located if it is placed? So, if it is >0, get store name/location. If 0, it means it is not placed.

Comment: Can't you just specify `store_id` as nullable? So if `store_id=null`, it means that your item is not placed.

Comment: Existing system of placed and unplaced seems neater.